# Issue with UIDocumentMenuViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, icloud-drive

I have implemented UIDocumentMenuViewController in my application with below code

```
_importMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:[MingleUtils allowedUTIs] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
_importMenu.delegate = self;
 [self presentViewController:_importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It is working but picker is taking time to appear and sometimes getting error "**couldnt comunicate with helper application**" 
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: see this link may be help with you http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-fix-couldnt-communicate-with-a-helper-application-in-xcode-7/

Comment: It couldn't help me.Thanks @Anbu.Karthik